# Mvn install bypass verify phase

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

I am looking for solution as to bypass verify phase in mvn install.

Setup is set to install all dependencies, but also verify phase is set for Cucumber reporting that fails on mvn install. Plan is to have mvn install and then to run mvn test verify. But with mvn install, it does verify and build fails.

Comment: If your Cucumber reporting is failing than simply fix it?...And why do you use `mvn install`? and not only `mvn verify`?

Comment: @khmarbaise it is not failing on regular mvn test part, framework is set to join several modules and requires to install several dependencies from other modules, thus mvn install is used for that, but no need for mvn verify in that part

Answer (score 0):

You can't skip entire phases in maven. What you can do is to skip plugin executions. I dont't know about the plugin you use but lets have a look at [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#skipAssembly). Now when you call `mvn install -Dassembly.skipAssembly=true` the maven-assembly-plugin will get called in phase `package` but the executions are skipped. You can also move the cucumber plugin to a [profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and execute maven with `mvn install` and then `mvn verify -Pcucumber-profile-id`.

Also `mvn test verfiy` is redundant because when you call `verify` the `test` phase is executed -> [introduction-to-the-lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)